# Using sidemenu cocoapods and to keep the 'state of data' for all VCs

Tags: swift3, side-menu

I am trying to use the same side menu for 2 viewcontrollers on the sidemenu demo project. See image
[setup of menu using their demo project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSZCx.png)

I am able to set up the 2 cells on the menu which will open the 2 VCs base on what i tap but trying to find out if i can keep the 'state of data' on the VC.

To know how many times the VCs are loaded/appear into the view, i inserted 'print to console' into viewdidload and viewdidappear of the 2 VCs.
I set VC 1 as the root view controller. If I tab VC 1 on the menu,  it will only 'print viewdidload+viewdidappear' once and just 'print viewdidappear the next time I tab it. This is correct and what i need similar like a 'tab controller feature'. However, for VC 2, it will print 'viewdidload+viewdidappear' all the time which means the view keeps 'reloading'. But i would like to keep the 'state of data' just like VC1.

So if i switch VC 2 as the rootviewcontroller, then VC 2 will keep the 'state of data' and VC 1 will not. I tried 'menuPushStyle: MenuPushStyle = .defaultBehavior, - popWhenPossible, preserve, preserveAndHideBackButton' but can't make it work.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No. Looking for help too :(

Comment: Sad... I ended up reverting back to https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController, which works great and lets me reuse the view controllers (keeping references as ivars).